# Buddhist canon database

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request, buddhism

Is there an online database that either contains the Buddhist canon in either English or Chinese?

I've had a difficult time tracking down first hand sources other than the usual suspects (Heart Sutra, Prajnaparamita sutra, etc). I've been looking for anything related to pratityasamutpada in the abhidharma, but I don't even know where to look, or even if English translations exist.

Does anyone know where to look?

Comment: You might want to try https://buddhism.stackexchange.com

Comment: I made an edit which you may roll back or continue editing. You can see the versions by clicking on the "edited" link above. Welcome to this SE!

Comment: My first guess was going to be ctext.org but I didn't see classic buddhist texts there.

Comment: yeah ctext only has original chinese sources, but not even original Buddhist sources written in China such as 坛经

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial answer since I know little about Buddhism, however, I have found the following sites useful for other purposes.

The [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/) may contain works of interest.  By copying the word "pratityasamutpada" and pasting it in their Search box I was able to find this text: *[Pratityasamutpada In The Abhidharmasamuccaya, Kritzer, 1995](https://archive.org/details/PratityasamutpadaInTheAbhidharmasamuccayaKritzer1995/page/n0)*  You may be able to find other texts of interest there.

The [Internet Sacred Text Archive](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/) contains works related to Buddhism:  Searching there may provide something of interest.

---

Reference

Internet Archive: https://archive.org/

Internet Sacred Text Archive: http://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/

Comment: I'll definitely look around on the Internet Archive, but I've tried the Internet Sacred Text Archive before, and couldn't find what I was looking for, and their collection is not even remotely complete.